# how can receive information from non activity to activity class

Tags: java, android, jdbc

i have to class in my android project, first class is Main Activity that is extend Activity, the another class is MSSQLConnect which is a simple class to get data from database and return it as arraylist

i use this method to call a MSSQLConnect class but it doesn't work:

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


MSSQLConnect cdb = new MSSQLConnect("id", "mytable", "", "");
Toast.makeText(this, cdb.getdata("getApplicationContext()"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }}
```

MSSQLConnect class :

```
public class MSSQLConnect extends ContextWrapper {


private final String table;
private final String columns;
private final String whereColumn;
private final String equalsEntry;


public MSSQLConnect (Context context, String columns, String table, String whereColumn, String equalsEntry) {
    super(context);
    this.table = table;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.whereColumn = whereColumn;
    this.equalsEntry = equalsEntry;

}

static String JDBC_DRIVER = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
static String DB_URL ="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.x:xxx;DatabaseName=xxxx";

//  Database credentials
static String USER = "xxxxx";
static String PASS = "xxxxx";

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ourQuerryMethod () {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    String data[][] = null;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> setData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    try {
        Class.forName(getJDBC_DRIVER());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getDB_URL(), getUSER(), getPASS());
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        if(whereColumn.equals("") && equalsEntry.equals(""))
        {
             sql = "SELECT " + (columns) + " FROM " + (table);
        }
        else
             sql = "SELECT " + (columns) + " FROM " + (table) + " WHERE "+ (whereColumn) +" = "+ (equalsEntry) +"";

        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            int nc = 1;
            ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
            int rowCount =0;
            while(rs.next()) // loop rows
            {

                rowCount++;
                if(rowCount == 1)
                {
                    while(true){ //loop columns
                        try {
                            columns.add(rs.getString(nc));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception

                            break;
                        }
                        nc++;
                    }
                }

                int rrowrr = 0;
                for(int i=1;i<nc;i++)
                {
                    rrowrr++;
                    if(rrowrr == 1)
                    {
                        setData.add(new ArrayList<String>());
                    }
                    setData.get(rs.getRow()-1).add(rs.getString(i));
                }

            }
        rs.close();
    }catch (SQLException se) {
        // Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("DBError1", se.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("DBError2", e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        // finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.d("DBError3", se.getMessage());

        }
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("DBError4", se.getMessage());

        } // end finally try
    } // end try
    return setData;
} // end main

public static String getJDBC_DRIVER() {
    return JDBC_DRIVER;
}
public static void setJDBC_DRIVER(String aJDBC_DRIVER) {
    JDBC_DRIVER = aJDBC_DRIVER;
}

public static String getDB_URL() {
    return DB_URL;
}


public static void setDB_URL(String aDB_URL) {
    DB_URL = aDB_URL;
}


public static String getUSER() {
    return USER;
}

public static void setUSER(String aUSER) {
    USER = aUSER;
}
public static String getPASS() {
    return PASS;
}

public static void setPASS(String aPASS) {
    PASS = aPASS;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
MSSQLConnect connect=new MSSQLConnect();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list=connect.ourQuerryMethod();

ConnectDB cdb = new ConnectDB("id", "mytable", "", "");
Toast.makeText(this, cdb.getdata("getApplicationContext()"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }}
```

Comment: MSSQLConnect class and ConnectDB class are the same.

Comment: then use this above method

Answer (score 0):

JDBC for android??? Are you crazy? I suggest you to use php page for sql query and parse it in json with asynctask, but if you like JDBC I ask you a few question, why MSSQLConnect class is renamed to ConnectDB? And MSSQLConnect builder have 5 arguments but you had create the object with 4 arguments??

Comment: actually i tried a lot to use c# but it doesn't work for me, and when i use JDBC in  java project it works fine.

Comment: Yeah great, but the constructor ispublic MSSQLConnect (Context context, String columns, String table, String whereColumn, String equalsEntry) and you had create MSSQL object with 4 element...check it and try